# How do i set x to be a negative value if x is positive, and if x is positive how do i set it to be negative. c++

Tags: c++

I am making an AI/algorithm to find a checker pattern in a 2x2 square. I need them to be negative for hidden_1 and hidden_3, but positive for the other 2.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>  
    
using namespace std;
    
int main (){
    int x;
    int y;
    int a;
    int b;
    int x1 = -x;
    int y1 = -y;
    int a1 = -a;
    int b1 = -b;
    cout << "Is there a square in the top left?\n1 for Yes/-1 for No\n";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Is there a square in the bottom right?\n1 for Yes/-1 for No\n";
    cin >> y;
    cout << "Is there a square in the bottom left?\n1 for Yes/-1 for No\n";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Is there a square in the top right?\n1 for Yes/-1 for No\n";
    cin >> b;


    int hidden_1 << x1 + y1 + -1;
    int hidden_2 << x + y + -1;
    int hidden_3 << a1 + b1 + -1;
    int hidden_4 << a + b + -1;
```

Comment: its not clear how the code you posted relates to the question in the title. `-x` is positive when `x` is negative and positive when `x` is negative

Comment: the actual problem in your code is taht you are using variables before you initialized them with user input. Turn on warnings to see whats wrong

Comment: You use `x`, `y`, `a`, and `b` uninitialized. Remember, statements in C++ are sequential. Variables are not spreadsheet cells.

Comment: `int hidden_1 << x1 + y1 + -1;` ?!? Thats not valid syntax. And you should include the c++ versions of C headers if you need them (you don't need `math.h` nor `string.h` and you should include `cmath` and `cstring`)

Comment: Just do `int hidden_1 = -x - y - 1;`, (or `-(x + y + 1)`) and `int hidden_3 = -a - b - 1;`.

Comment: I'll ask -- why did you write code that assumed that variables worked this way, where you assumed they work in a spreadsheet style, as @FredLarson mentioned?  The task doesn't seem like a complete beginner task, so it's surprising (at least to me) that you made this mistake.

Comment: Wow, all that code, and not even compilable, to ask a question that could be illustrated with one line? Post the **smallest** example you can come up with that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You initialised x1, y1, a1, b1 with negatives of variables that weren't read. Try declare them after you read x, y, a, b.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>  

using namespace std;

int main () {
  int x;
  int y;
  int a;
  int b;

  cout << "Is there a square in the top left?\n1 for Yes/-1 for No\n";
  cin >> x;
  cout << "Is there a square in the bottom right?\n1 for Yes/-1 for No\n";
  cin >> y;
  cout << "Is there a square in the bottom left?\n1 for Yes/-1 for No\n";
  cin >> a;
  cout << "Is there a square in the top right?\n1 for Yes/-1 for No\n";
  cin >> b;

  int x1 = -x;
  int y1 = -y;
  int a1 = -a;
  int b1 = -b;

  int hidden_1 = x1 + y1 + -1;
  int hidden_2 = x + y + -1;
  int hidden_3 = a1 + b1 + -1;
  int hidden_4 = a + b + -1;
```

Comment: What did you change and why? Explaining is more important than providing code.

Comment: Oh sorry, first post. I'll take note.

Comment: @ReisHarnishfeger churill's comment wasn't directed towards you :-)